# Unique numeric connection id from fileno and server instance

Tags: perl, sockets, websocket, publish-subscribe

I'm working on some WebSocket/PubSub code.

I'm generating a simple unique *active* client id like so:

```
my $connId =  $server_id . '-' . fileno($sock);
```

Works fine as fileno($sock) will always be unique per server, and adding the $server_id makes it unique across all servers.

For the next branch however, it would be convenient if I could make my $connId simply an integer.
So, looking for some nice XOR or other speedy logic to prevent collisions without needing the -.

UUID's would be overkill as I only need be concerned with active connections.

Comment: what is server id?  if an integer, what is the range?

Comment: Is that $server_id an integer? If it is, how about using `$server_id . fileno($sock)` as your new `$connId`?

Comment: As long as you don't close/reopen your sockets, fileno will be unique throughout your program, not just per server.

Comment: @Guntram as long as I'm on the same server yes.  I'm not.

Comment: @leeduhem yes, they both are integers.  That won't work with a straight integer.  As soon as my fileno increments to the hundreds range, how would I tell the difference between server 2 connection 12 and server 21, connection 2?

Comment: @ysth server id is anything I want it to be.  Right now it's an int.  fileno appears to start at 1 and just increment per connection.  Thought about just multiplying server_id by a million then adding fileno, but not sure where fileno rolls over.

Comment: "if an integer, what is the range?"

Comment: Ok, so you have several servers (either several pieces of hardware, or several independent on one server) - i didn't get that part. As long as you're on a linux or unix system, you can use `ulimit -n` to check the maximum number of file descriptors,  which should be 1024 or less. So servernumber * 10000 + descriptor should work. Or, use ysth's idea, just multiply the file descriptor with 100 (assuming you have less than 100 servers) and add the server number.

Comment: Hmm.  Well there is two points.  I need to up my ulimit (it's all Event based, so I was planning for about 25k concurrent connections), , and ulimit -n is the key to my server_number multiplier range.  That explains why ApacheBench wouldn't go much above 600 concurrency too.  Silly the things you forget.  No XOR magic for me.  Make it an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: what you are calling xor magic is basically the same as @GuntramBlohm and I are suggesting, only a bitmask based approach uses the integer space less efficiently (resulting in higher numbers) unless the range is a power of 2.

Comment: It looks like the idea I intended to suggest has already been suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $min_server_id = 1;
my $max_server_id = 12;

my $connId = fileno($sock) * ( $max_server_id - $min_server_id + 1) + ( $server_id - $min_server_id );


# later:
my $sock_fileno = int( $connId / ( $max_server_id - $min_server_id + 1 ) );
my $server_id = $connId % ( $max_server_id - $min_server_id + 1 ) + $min_server_id;
```

Comment: I'll try it out in a few hours.  Another motivation for int's is inter-user chatter also sends the connection id, so uuid's would out-weigh the actual messages most of the time.  That and int better aligns me with WAMP (Websocket application message protocol).

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit -n` tells you how many files you can have, this coincides with the maximum number a file descriptor, as returned by fileno, can have. So use a multiplier that's larger that that - i'd recommend the next power of 10 - and multiply your server number with it, then add `fileno`.